# Tastypie to respond for every requests in Json format

Tags: django, json, tastypie

I am working on Api for my project, i'm using Tastypie 9.9.0. I want the response in Json format for PUT, POST and DELETE operations.

The existing responses like STATUS 201 CREATED, STATUS 204 NO CONTENT, STATUS 410 GONE is fine.

It must respond in a custom format. 
   for example

```
1.  {
        "resource_name": "user",
        "action":"password_reset",
        "status": "success" 
    }

2.  {
      "resource_name": "todo",
      "action":"insert",
      "status":"sucess",
    }
3.  {
      "resource_name": "todo",
      "action":"delete",
      "status":"sucess",
    }
```

this is the code i was working on. I dont know how to add custom response messages

```
  class ToDoResource(ModelResource):
        user = fields.ToOneField(UserResource, 'user')

        class Meta:
            queryset = ToDo.objects.all()
            fields=['alert_time','description','status','user']
            resource_name = 'todo'
            filtering = {
                         'user': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
                         'alert_time': ['exact', 'range', 'gt', 'gte', 'lt', 'lte'],
                        }
            serializer = Serializer()
            authentication= MyApiKeyAuthentication()
            authorization=Authorization()
            always_return_data = True
            allowed_methods = ['post','get','put','delete']


        def obj_create(self, bundle,request=None, **kwargs):
            if not request.user.is_superuser:
                try:
                    bundle.data.pop('user')
                except:
                    pass
            return super(ToDoResource, self).obj_create(bundle, request, user=request.user)

        def create_response(self, request, data):
            """
            Extracts the common "which-format/serialize/return-response" cycle.

            Mostly a useful shortcut/hook.
            """
            desired_format = self.determine_format(request)
            serialized = self.serialize(request, data, desired_format)
            return HttpResponse(content=serialized, content_type=build_content_type(desired_format))

        def apply_authorization_limits(self, request, object_list):
            return object_list.filter(user=request.user)
```

Comment: It is not clear as to what `action` and `status` refer to in context of a http response.

Answer (score 0):

You can add/modify custom data in `get_list(request, **kwargs)` and/or `get_object(request, **kwargs)`

For example,

```
import json
from django.http import HttpResponse

class ToDoResource(ModelResource):
    # ... the rest of code
    def get_list(self, request, **kwargs):
        resp = super(ToDoResource, self).get_list(request, **kwargs)
        data = json.loads(resp.content)

        # ... the rest of code

        data['meta']['resource_name'] = self._meta.resource_name
        data['meta']['action'] = request.method
        data['meta']['status'] = ANY_STATUS

        # ... the rest of code

        data = json.dumps(data)

        return HttpResponse(data, mimetype='application/json', status=ANY_STATUS)
```